# Breakpoint not set

Tags: actionscript-3

Super helpful forums over here! 
I've recently started back up in as3 and have created a small tile based game. It's far from done but i recently ran into a snag and i've no idea how to fix it!
I have a function where when i click on a tile it checks if is  intractable property is true and if it is i do whatever. When i test the fla using ctrl-enter, i get  no errors and i can click tiles and everything works fine. However, whenever i test it using Ctrl-Shift-Enter, i get this:

```
Breakpoint not set; No executable code at line 124 of Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1
```

And if i click a tile that is intractable  the player stops responding and crashes.
--> Line 124 is a comment ..... ?
I'm very confused, Since i can't locate the error it will be hard to post helpful parts of my code. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, post some code and especially line 124, so we can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've put a breakpoint on the comment line, and when running it debug mode, it crashes because it can't break on a comment.

You may have accidentally clicked the margin on line 124 in whatever IDE you're using. See if you can disable the breakpoint at that line.

Comment: Wow, that was it haha! I had no idea what a breakpoint was, i think i understand now. However, the program still crashes in debug mode when i click on an interactable type and not with just ctrl-enter which eludes me lol!

Comment: You may have another breakpoint elsewhere. A breakpoint basically stops/pauses the execution of the program when that line of code is reached. It will appear as though the program is crashed/hung, but it's just paused. Debugging this way is very, very valuable. You should try to learn some basic debugging in your IDE.

Comment: Ahh, right you are! Inside a collapsed function. Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy!